# how to use rewriterule to change url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My url is:

```
http://domain:1111/m3u8/play.php?fileid=2&userid=1
```

when I use it to watch file it is ok and I can watch file normal

I want to use a URL like this:

```
http://domain:1111/2/1
```

And redirect to:

```
http://domain:1111/m3u8/play.php?fileid=2&userid=1
```

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)/?$ /play.php?fileid=$1&userid=$2 [L]
```

It redirects correctly, but the video is not working.

Comment: You're missing the `/m3u8/` part in your redirect rule.

Comment: aha yes i add sorry but the same problem

Comment: when i open url from browser its the same result for both urls

Comment: it get the file but not play

Comment: If you get the file then the problem is not related to the rewrite. Are you using relative paths in your file? That would cause problems.

Comment: yes my file use relative path
#EXTM3U #EXT-X-VERSION:3 #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6 #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:33 #EXTINF:3.128133, film33.ts #EXTINF:3.461789, film34.ts #EXTINF:5.046711, film35.ts #EXTINF:2.335667, film36.ts #EXTINF:2.961289, film37.ts

so ...... ????